Doubt regarding Kali's one of name
I was going through 108 names of Goddess Kali, and came across one name 'kalahpriyaye'
I searched on Google about it, and got little info like it is one of Yoginis mentioned in some Tantra texts. And it's name meaning is 'One who Likes quarrels.'
My main doubt is why is Goddess Kali called so? Like why does she described as per name as One who likes Quarrels?
Thanks for clearing my doubt.
